# Switching to terraform module for google pubsub recreating the topic and subscription

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to switch to [GCP pubsub module](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-pubsub) but on terraform plan is showing the topic resource will be recreated even though the variables are exactly the same. Is it possible that these resources do not need to be recreated at least the topic?

###### New way

```
module "pubsub" {
  source  = "terraform-google-modules/pubsub/google"
  version = "~> 1.8"

  topic        = "topic_name"
  create_topic = false
  project_id   = local.project_id

  pull_subscriptions = [
    {
      name                    = "sub_name"
      ack_deadline_seconds    = 10
    }
  ]

  topic_labels  = {
    app = "l1"
  }

  subscription_labels = {
    app = "l1"
  }
}
```

###### Old way

```
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "topic" {
  name = "topic_name"
  labels = {
    app = "l1"
  }
}

resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "sub" {
  name  = "sub_name"
  topic = google_pubsub_topic.topic.name

  labels = {
    app = "l1"
  }

  ack_deadline_seconds = 10
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not the same since the old way used `resource` blocks while the new one is using `module` block. That means that the address in the state file is different. In order to avoid that, you can import the already created topic and subscription to the module. An example of how to import an existing resource into the module [1]:

```
terraform import module.foo.aws_instance.bar i-abcd1234
```

In the case when importing something into modules, the syntax is as follows:

```
module.<module name>.<resource type>.<logical name>
```

Since you have set the `create_topic` variable to `false`, the topic will not be created (`count` will evaluate to 0) [2] and you will not be able to import it into state. To fix this, you need to set it to `true`. Now, in your case, for the topic [3] that would be something along the lines:

```
terraform import 'module.pubsub.google_pubsub_topic.topic[0]' <topic id>
```

and for the subscription [4]:

```
terraform import 'module.pubsub.google_pubsub_subscription.pull_subscriptions["sub_name"]' <subscription id>
```

An example on which IDs are acceptable for a topic can be found in [5]. An example on which IDs are acceptable for a subscription can be found in [6].

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/import#example-import-into-module

[2] https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-pubsub/blob/master/main.tf#L94

[3] https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-pubsub/blob/master/main.tf#L93

[4] https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-pubsub/blob/master/main.tf#L197

[5] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/pubsub_topic#import

[6] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/pubsub_subscription#import

Comment: I imported the existing resource into the module and the command is successful. Now, on terraform plan shows both the resources (module and non-module) are being deleted and no one is being created. ```terraform import module.pubsub.google_pubsub_subscription.pull_subscriptions[0] <sub_id>```. I was expecting `no changes`.

Comment: Have you removed the resource blocks?

Comment: Also, I did not notice that the subscription was created with for_each. So you probably need to remove it from the state and re-import it with a key that corresponds to the name, i.e. to whichever value `name = "sub name"` is actually equal to. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for editing! After following your guide, getting ```# module.exp_pubsub.google_pubsub_subscription.pull_subscriptions["exp-sub"] will be destroyed
  # (because key ["exp-sub"] is not in for_each map)```

Comment: Is the `name` for the `subscription` actually set to `exp-sub`?

Comment: yes it is set to `exp-sub`

Comment: Ah wait, when you are invoking the module, did you assign it the name `pubsub` or `exp_pubsub`? That is really an important difference when doing imports.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246877/discussion-between-kamal-and-marko-e).